# Minumum Spanning Tree

Tags: graph-theory

I have a homework about graph and minimum spanning tree

Suppose for a given graph G1, we have computed a minimum spanning tree T1. Now ,a new edge to G1 is added.We call this new graph with the added edge G2. Describe an algorithm to compute the minimum spanning tree T2 OF G2 efficiently by jut adjusting T1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read over the FAQ, if it's homework, that's ok - tell us what you've done or thought of so far. Also, try to make the minimum effort on spelling and grammar before you post, it really does help responses!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that new edge, say e', to T1, this will form a cycle in T1. Your problem have been reduced to finding the maximum weighted edge in the unique cycle of T1 + e'.

If you remove the edge that you found by the previous procedure from T1 + e', you will obtain T2.